# How to add SearchView to action bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, searchview, actionview

In the following snippet, what does `yourapp` refer to? I try using the package name, then the project name, but they aren't the answer as the code does not compile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: also I am going for `android:minSdkVersion="11"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597139/onquerytextlistenercompat-not-getting-triggered/25598002#25598002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to use `SearchView` in API less than 11 (obviously you are not) you must extend your activity from `ActionBarCompat`and in your xml layout of your menu you must use another xml name space for `showAsAction` and `actionViewClass`. then you must use searchview from support library.`(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView)` the xml name space is arbitary and here you called it `yourapp`. So you must use below code because of  `android:minSdkVersion="11"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: so `yourapp` is simply `android`. It works. So I am not sure why google's official documents made a distinction: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Comment: because searchview is introduced in API 11 and for supporting API<11 it creates this trick. also for API<11 it is not android.